# How do I create form controls (radio, checkbox, buttons, etc.) in Excel using Apache POI (Java)?

Tags: java, excel

Is it possible for me to produce form controls for Excel with Apache POI library using Java? If this is not possible, what are the alternative?

I really need this to accomplish my works.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For Excel 2007 or above, because Apache POI operates on OpenXML, you need to use VML Drawing. The fastest path to produce form controls is to do that manually, then open created xlsx or xlam as a zip archive and look at the `/xl/drawings/vmldrawing.vml` part. Then read about VML Drawing in [OpenXML standard (ECMA-376)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) for basics on creating VML drawings. The approach is to create `vmldrawing.vml` part programmatically as regular XML container and fill it with XML code serialized from memory objects supported by Apache POI API appropriately.