# How do I create Excel files with form controls using Java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a Java application that uses the Apache POI library to build XLSX files. I have a customer who has an XLSX template with form controls (mostly list boxes and comobo boxes; not ActiveX, just regular form controls).

We need to create XLSX files that replicate this template format; filling it in with pre-populated data. However, I cannot find a lot of information on how to create XLSX files with populated form controls from Java. The only post here I could find about it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578459/how-do-i-create-form-controls-radio-checkbox-buttons-etc-in-excel-using-ap).

We currently use the Apache POI library but I am open to alternate libraries that might be able to accomplish this easier, or even a mixed Java / VBA approach if that is the only way. Appreciate any help or insight, thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if copying of a row via POI would include the form controls (since I assume you will have a variable number of rows), but maybe an approach where you make a copy of the template, then simply populate the content instead of creating the form controls is viable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Excel file template containing all of the form controls that you need, and store the actual Excel file inside your application jar file. Then from within your application you can open up the template file using POI, fill in the template with the data you require, and write out the new file to the local file system. For example:

```
outFile = new File("/myfiles", "table1.xlsx");
try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outFile)) {
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/myapp/templates/template1.xlsx");
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    // Now populate the table here as your application requires
    wb.write(fileOut);
}
```